# Disasble shiny sliderInput using shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am building multiple lm() models using dplyr. I want to allow a user to change the independent variable value in a Shiny app - via shiny::sliderInput(). But only do so where "goodness of fit" say R^2 is greater than a threshold - otherwise disable the slider. I have tried to use the shinyjs::disable() function. See below, but can't get it to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("test","Nice number",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)
      ),
    mainPanel(
        textOutput("valueText")
      )
   )
))

# Define server to disable slider if value selected

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  value <- reactive(input$test)
   output$valueText <- renderText(paste(value()))

   #How to diasble slider?
      reactive(if(value()==35){
       shinyjs::disable('test')
     }
   )
   })

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call useShinyjs() in ui.R.

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)

    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- shinyUI(
            tagList(
            useShinyjs(),
            fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                            sliderInput("test","Nice number",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                            textOutput("valueText")
                    )
            )
    )

    )
    )

    # Define server to disable slider if value selected

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            value <- reactive(input$test)
            output$valueText <- renderText(paste(value()))

            #How to diasble slider?
            observeEvent(value(), {
                    if(value()==35){
                            shinyjs::disable('test')
                    }  
            })

    })

    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```